# How to make pass variables through CallActivity in Activiti correctly?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I'm calling sub process from main process. I'm using Alfresco Activiti 7.1.0.M3.1.
Sub process starting without a problem, but when I'm trying to get variables in it with `execution.getVariables()`
or
`execution.getVariable("par1")`
I get nothing. (empty map or null)
This is the way I'm setting variable in main process:

```
<callActivity id="callactivity1" name="Call activity" calledElement="myProcess2" >
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:in source="var1i" target="par1"></activiti:in>
        <activiti:out source="par1" target="var1i"></activiti:out>
        <activiti:executionListener event="start" delegateExpression="${executionListener}"></activiti:executionListener>
        <activiti:executionListener event="end" delegateExpression="${executionListener}"></activiti:executionListener>
      </extensionElements>
</callActivity>
```

I found a flag in callActivity: `callActivity.isInheritVariables()` with this flag *true* (it can't be set from Eclipse, only from java), then variables passing to sub process but with the same names as in main process (var1i). And when I change this variable in sub process, it doesn't return to main.

I read carefully docs: https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCallActivity and doing exactly as it written in it. It doesn't seemed to work.

I see the way to write own implementation CallActivityBehavior and to set it to engine, and it will work, but in docs it should work from default configuration.
What I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First you have tried to reach root process instance with;

```
ExecutionEntity thisEntity = (ExecutionEntity) execution;

ExecutionEntity pi= (ExecutionEntityImpl) thisEntity.getRootProcessInstance()
```

Please take a look on this link below,

https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-process-services/is-there-any-way-to-pass-transient-variable-to-inner-call/td-p/50564

Comment: Yes. Context is one of the way how I can get variables. Another way is to override __CallActivityBehavior__ and to set it to engine. Like: ```engineConfiguration.setActivityBehaviorFactory(new CustomActivityBehaviorFactory());```
But what I need is to pass variables correctly, as it written in documentation. With changing variable names. Custom implementation looks wierd if the engine should work by default configuration. I saw forums, where people had problems with multi instance calling CallActivity. They wrote that default works correctly, and the multi instance doesn't. I still missing

Comment: Instead, I suggest you collect the variables into a list or array and pass them into the sub-process that way.

You can collect the variables in an executionListener by calling execution.getVariables(), this will return a map of the variables in the execution, you can then assign this list to a local (task scoped) variable that you set as an input to the called activity.

This way, the task local variable disappears as soon as you return from the called activity and you aren't passing in more than you need to the called activity.